# setPresence not setting a custom rich presence but presents status well (discordjs)

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm currently using discordjs v12 to make my bot, and while setting up a custom rich presence to display the amount of members it's watching, the stats and writing itself doesnt appear, however the status "idle" does.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "idle",
        game: {
            name: `!help for commands | Watching shukakucult server with ${client.users.cache.size} members.`,
            type: "PLAYING"
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

found the fix,, game is not a valid propery. it should've been activity